# Using regular expressions to split() values in a CSV file

Tags: php, regex, csv, split

I have a CSV file which I am parsing.

I am using split() to split the columns up by their commas.

The problem is that it is splitting columns that contain commas within the field.

The solution is to use a regular expression in the split to disregard commas with a space after them (EG: ", ") and only split commas with no trailing space (EG: ",").

Right now my split looks like this:

```
$div = ',';
split('$div',$line);
```

How would I modify my split() call?

Comment: Do you have any enclosure character? Like `"`? On a sidenote, have you considered [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)?

Comment: Why don't you use `fgetcsv()` or `str_getcsv()`?

Comment: what variable is having your column names?

Comment: Sounds like your CSV format is inconsistent. Sparse commas should be escaped or within double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

To parse a complete and valid CSV file with PHP you just need:

```
$data = array_map("str_getcsv", file($fn));
```

But if your file format is really not consistent, then you would indeed need the manual split method and a more specific regex.

```
preg_split('/,(?!\s)/', $line)
```

would be the regex you can use to match commans that are not followed by a space. Note that you need to use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) from the PCRE library, and not the older [`split`](http://php.net/split) call.

Answer (score 1):

The CSV file's fields (especially if fields have commas in them) should be encapsulated in quotes:

```
 "A","B1,B2","C","D"
```

If they are not, then that ambiguity is your first problem:

```
 A,B1,B2,C,D
```

has five fields, and there's nothing you can do about it<sup>1</sup>.

When you have your source data sorted out, use [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to parse it.

---

<sup>1</sup> If this is really true:

> The solution is to use a regular expression in the split to disregard commas with a space after them (EG: ", ") and only split commas with no trailing space (EG: ",").

that all your "internal" commas have spaces after them, then you could run a pre-processing step, replacing all `,<space>` with `\,`. Escaping the commas within CSV resolves the ambiguity:

```
A,B1\,B2,C,D
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a CSV file which I am parsing.

You're reinventing the wheel: PHP has fine methods of accomplishing this by itself, namely [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php):

```
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use them as a string. like this

```
$outstr .='"'.$line->linename.'",';
```

Comment: Don't forget to convert quotes in `$line->linename` to double-quotes.

Comment: @binaryLV hi dude thanks. I think I have used double-quotes. Is it not or I am unable to understand your point?

Comment: double-quotes in string should be escaped with another double-quote, i.e., `$line->linename` should be `str_replace('"', '""', $line->linename)`. If you have 3 values, `a`, `b"c` and `d`, they should result in `"a","b""c","d"` and not `"a","b"c","d"`.

Comment: There's no need for trailing comma. If there are 5 values to be stored, there should be 4 commas (not including commas that are parts of values).